# How can i solve the The operation has timed out in web service call?

Tags: c#

I'm new in c# and want to call the web service with this code:

```
CRMWEBSERVICE.behzad myService = new CRMWEBSERVICE.behzad ();
var result=myService.BackRials("2", "1002");
```

but when I run that, get the this error:

> The operation has timed out

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: do you get error on first line?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev get that error in var result=myService.BackRials("2", "1002"); line

Comment: Is your webservice accesible? Did you check, while connecting web service there is no problem? If you are accesing web service without problem, so in BackRails method you have infinite loop, or non accesible service. Can you share BackRails codes?

Comment: yes i check that in browser and wsdl show me without problem

Comment: Back Rials not my code and on the other province server hosted

Comment: can you check BackRails method from browser? Is that working?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev yes Back Rials work correct in browser

Comment: How long have you waited on browser? Try Timeout=int.MaxValue of myService

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev about 5 minute

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev can you post code for how can use timeout=int.maxvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you waited 5 min in browser so increase timeout property from caller

```
myService.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
```

Comment: For who downvoted, it solved timeout error. Can you explain reason of downvote